# Repository->findAll gives unknown database error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I just started out using symfony. I installed SF4 with twig, doctrine maker, ...

I created my database 'Autotrader', I created a migration and migrated it.

But whenever I try to get the data from the database I get the following error:

[image: screenshot of error]

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Car;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class CarController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:Car');
        $cars = $repository->findAll();

        return $this->render('Car/list.html.twig', array(
            "title" => "Our cars",
            'cars' => $cars
        ));
    }
}
```

Parameter config:

```
parameters:
# Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
# This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
# environment variables are not available yet.
# You should not need to change this value.
env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: 'utf8mb4'
        dbname:               'autotrader'
        host:                 '127.0.0.1'
        port:                  3306
        user:                 'root'
        password:             'secret'

        # With Symfony 3.3, remove the `resolve:` prefix
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Comment: it says right there: "Unknown database: Autotrader"

Comment: Yes, but if I check Sequel Pro, the database is right there

Comment: Give us your parameter configuration please

Comment: doctrine.yaml is added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.
I was running my app in vagrant/homestead and migrated localy, no wonder the DB wasn't found

Answer (score 0):

This is the unknown database error.

Are you sure you have created Autotrader db at the correct localhost path and the port number mentioned in doctrine.yml file?

Also, In your doctrine.yml replace 
`dbname: 'autotrader'` with `dbname: Autotrader`
and try again!!

Comment: I edited my db so it has no capital in its name, that's why it says 'autotrader'. As said before, the path should be correct since it's the same path I used for creating and migrating with the cli

Comment: You might be making some mistake because the error is very clear - it is not finding the database called Autotrader at the location mysql:://root:secret@120.0.0.1:3306.